# what's different IEnumerator and IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to know difference IEnumerator and IEnumerable. This is a question I got when I was using coroutine. what they have difference? And do they have different uses? It's the biggest question using C# and Unity, but it's hard to understand. I want to learn about that easily.

I found they difference, but I don't understand that's Description.

Comment: an eunmer*able* is - well iterable. You can iterate it. The enumerator is used to do that.

Comment: IEnumerator is the enumerator itself, IEnumerable is an interface which allows you to return something. For example, System.Collections.Generic.List<T> is IEnumerable, and returns an IEnumerator so you can use it in a for each.